# SSL missing in network's all sites page to Server Fault blog

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, ssl, blog-overflow

If we go to https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions Server Fault has a link to its old blog, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: all sites Server Fault blog link]

The link is missing SSL as can be seen in the code:

```html
<div class="lv-site-resources">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ServerFault">twitter</a>
        <a href="http://blog.serverfault.com">blog</a>
</div>
```

Although the blog does work with SSL https://blog.serverfault.com/

rev 2023.2.27.43262